# How to solve this type of coupled differential equations in MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

How to solve this type of coupled differential equations in MATLAB?

> dynamics through the following coupled density dynamics of singles ($S$), host triplets ($T_H$), guest triplets ($T_G$), and lasing mode photons ($P$).
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{dS}{dt} &= \frac{\eta I}{e_pd} -k_S S -k_{ISC} S -k_{ST} ST_G -\gamma\frac{c}{\eta_{eff}}P,   \tag{5.1}  \\
> \frac{dT_H}{dt} &= k_{ISC} S -k_{HG} \exp \left(-\frac{2}{L} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{N_0-T_G}}\right) T_H,   \tag{5.2}  \\
> \frac{dT_G}{dt} &= k_{HG} \exp \left(-\frac{2}{L} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{N_0-T_G}}\right) T_H,   \tag{5.3}  \\
> \frac{dP}{dt} &= (\Gamma\gamma -\alpha_{CAV} -\Gamma \sigma_{TT} T_G) \frac{c}{\eta_{eff}} P +\Gamma\beta k_S S,   \tag{5.4}
> \end{align}
>   The coefficients are
>   $$\begin{array}{ll|ll}
> \hline
> d \text{ (nm)} & 200 & L \text{ (nm)} & 1  \\
> k_S \text{ (s}^{-1}\text{)} & 6.7 \times 10^8 & N_0 \text{ (cm}^{-3}\text{)} & 9.2 \times 10^{17}  \\ 
> k_{ISC} \text{ (s}^{-1}\text{)} & 1.3 \times 10^7 & \alpha_{CAV} \text{ (cm}^{-1}\text{)} & 10.4  \\
> k_{ST} \text{ (cm}^3\text{s}^{-1}\text{)} & 2 \times 10^{-12} & \Gamma & 0.69  \\
> \eta_{eff} & 1.6 & \sigma_{TT} \text{ (cm}^2\text{)} & 4.1 \times 10^{-17} \\
> k_{HG} \text{ (s}^{-1}\text{)} & 5 \times 10^{15} & \sigma_{stim} \text{ (cm}^2\text{)} & 2.3 \times 10^{-16}  
> \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$

Comment: This might be helpful https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a basic set of first order ODEs. `ode45` should be what you try first.